# Measurability of the derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis

A local analysis textbook I have used has the following exercise:

*Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional, $Y$ a separable Banach-space, $f\colon X\rightarrowtail Y$ any function. Show that $f'$ is Borel.*

I have no idea how to approach this. I looked at the proof of Rademacher, but even that only gives Lebesgue-measurability as far as I can see, and this has no assumptions on the function at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity (I'm not sure if this statement is true or not): Have you actual *need* for this statement or is it out of interest that you ask?

Comment: Can you do the case $X = Y = \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: I do not need it for an application now, it is more out of interest.

Comment: Even if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ I cannot approach this. I do not know what possible method could apply to functions like $id^2_\mathbb{R}\cdot\chi_A$ for any $A$. Should I bring this mathoverflow?

Comment: Define $f_n(x):=\frac{f(x + 1/n) - f(x)}{1/n}$... then...

Comment: Then... what then?

Comment: @Jonas T: This obviously works under the assumption of Borel or Lebesgue measurability, but we have *no assumptions whatsoever*.

Comment: I just remembered that I actually [answered this question on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49418/) in the case of $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ (it would be more precise to say that I provided some links to references). The extension to $X$ real and $Y$ separable should then be possible with some thinking as @GEdgar pointed out. (meta: include an `@username` somewhere in your comment, so that the user you want to address get notified), as I did in my two comments.

Comment: @Theo: Oh, right I missed that. I believe there is a proof in Bogachev. I should look it up.

Comment: @Theo, @scineram, are you sure this is even true for an arbitrary function?  I don't think it is without at least boundedness... this seems a little rough for an exercise.  Scineram, perhaps you can post some more context?  Which book exactly?

Comment: @Glen: I must admit that I haven't checked this in much detail since I had difficulty in seeing any need for such a statement (even for functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, to which I restrict in the following). It seems to me that where the derivative exists, it should be automatically Borel (even Baire class $1$) since $f$ has to be continuous there, so if one believes the theorem I mention in the answer on MO, one should be able to "drop" the $G_{\delta}$ and the $G_{\delta\sigma}$-null and modify $f'$ accordingly by setting it to be zero there.

Comment: @Glen: My guess is however that the suggestion by Jonas T is the one intended. I agree that a precise reference to the book would be a very good thing to have.

Comment: @Theo that's probably true.  I agree with you wholeheartedly on the applications question: I can't really think of a good use for such a statement.  Somewhat interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems my professor whose book I originally met this problem in [published the proof himself](https://eudml.org/doc/137077), generalizing the previous result of Federer for continuous functions. I was really surprised how much simpler it was than I expected.

In fact, I noticed the proof only requires that $L(X;Y)$ is separable, hence so are $X'$ and $Y$, since they embed into it. Given these, either of them being finite-dimensional is sufficient. It also raises the question whether $L(X;Y)$ can be separable when both spaces are infinite-dimensional. I read somewhere that this is an open problem when $X=Y$.